# Oracle 11g displaying ORA-01034, ORA-27101, and Linux "error 2" messages.

Tags: oracle-11g

When I try to connect to Oracle 11g using:

```
sqlplus noah/noah@orcl
```

I get these errors:

```
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

The service does start up when I connect as `sysdba` using:

```
sqlplus /nolog
conn / as sysdba
startup
```

Here's my `listener.ora`:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
  (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/112)
  (SID_NAME = orcl)
)
)

LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mylinux)(PORT = 1521))
)
```

And the `tnsnames.ora`:

```
ORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mylinux)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
)
)
```

Here is the `sqlnet.ora`:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,HOSTNAME)
```

Could anyone give me a hand making this work?

Comment: Did you start the listener? When you `conn / as sysdba`, you don't use it, but as soon as you specify a TNS entry like `@orcl`, you will

Comment: I've started it!

Comment: And what does `lsnrctl status` say? Do you see your `orcl` service?

Comment: Yes,the orcl service has started!

Comment: Are you sure the startup completes successfully? What is the status of your instance (eg: do a `SELECT status, instance_name FROM v$instance;` as a user with DBA privileges)

Comment: This error usually appears if the database has not started correctly. Check the alert log for errors.